# Centering Text around a Square Image

Tags: html, css

I basically have a square image depicting a diagram and what I would like to do is to be able to place url link descriptions of what the diagram represents at 12, 3, 6 and 9 o'clock positions.

All centered along the top, middle left and right of image as well as bottom.

Top and bottom url description links should be ok but I am unsure how to center my text on both the left and right hand side of the image.

Comment: I don't get it - is the element with a background-image the parent element of all the text descriptions? Maybe you could post your code, so that it would be easyer to solve the problem

Comment: Hi. Image is simply a background image, centered off on the page. 



Based on this image, I now want to place text around the outside borders of the background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use absolute positioning to place elements where you need them to be. Create a relatively positioned div. Set up image as a background for it and place all the elements within that div with absolute positioning. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is likely to use tables, but I've used a list and nested-list. There's a demo posted at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ahafa4/), using the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/mindez/css/stylesheet.css" />

  <style type="text/css" media="all">

  ul  {
    text-align: center;
    }

  ul li  {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    }

  ul li ul
    {
    }

  ul li ul li
    {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }

  ul li ul li img
    {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrap">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#linkOne">top link text</a></li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#linkTwo">left link text</a></li>
          <li><img src="http://image.bayimg.com/jaccdaabo.jpg" /></li>
          <li><a href="#linkThree">right link text</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#linkFour">bottom link text</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```